# How do I create a blank file on a MAC OS 10?

Tags: osx-mavericks

I need to create a blank file on my MAC OSX that has is totally empty. This file be a blank HTML file that will be inserted in my web site root directory.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `touch` command:

```
touch /path/to/file.html
```

Comment: Aside: this creates the file with the default permissions. @user320466, maybe you'd like a specific owner and specific permissions for the file in a web root directory; see `chown`, `chgrp` and `chmod` if applicable.